# What line width to use when making IOS7 style icons

Tags: icons, ios7

I'm about to start redrawing all our icons to the new IOS7 outline style. The question is: what is the best line width to use? Should it be double for retina images? Are there any other styling tips?

I've found styling guides for launch icons but nothing about creating the icons that go inside the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Icon sizes needed vary depending on the device, but you must include all sizes into your bundle. You also need to have standard resolution and high resolution icons. Here is the link for all sizes in px:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: Thanks Anna. However, my question is more to do with the design of the icon. eg, my IOS6 tab icons look awful in IOS7 and need modifying to the new 'hollow' design.